# IllegalSelectQueryException and InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, sql, spring, exception, jpa

I use Query annotation for my project. While I call query, I get `IllegalSelectQueryException`. I want to update status column which is on Reservation table with WHERE the PNR number exists.

```
@Repository
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation,String> {
    @Query("UPDATE Reservation SET Status =:Status WHERE pnr =:pnr")
    String setStatus( @Param("Status")String Status,@Param("pnr") String pnr);
}
```

Error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Expecting
> a SELECT query : `UPDATE Reservation SET Status = :Status WHERE pnr = :pnr`     at  Caused by: org.hibernate.query.IllegalSelectQueryException:
> Expecting a SELECT Query
> [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement], but found
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.update.SqmUpdateStatement [UPDATE
> Reservation SET Status = :Status WHERE pnr = :pnr]    at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmUtil.verifyIsSelectStatement(SqmUtil.java:81)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.verifySelect(QuerySqmImpl.java:499)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]     ... 102 common frames
> omitted

I tried changing the query but nothing works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying` annotation to the method and set the return value to `void`,because update queries can not return a value

```
@Repository
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation,String> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Reservation SET Status =:Status WHERE pnr =:pnr")
    void setStatus( @Param("Status")String Status,@Param("pnr") String pnr);
}
```